# Azure Logic - Bad gateway

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-logic-apps

I'm creating am Azure Logic App to add new Sharepoint files to an Azure Blob. The Sharepoint is run by my company and I log in with my credentials to create the Sharepoint API for the Logic App. It allows me to access the various sharepoint sites in the trigger set-up, but the next field displays "Bad Gateway" where it usually shows the folders. I've build several simple logic apps and never had this problem. I'm unsure where to even find an error message or anything that would help here.

Has anyone else had this issue? Can't find much online about it, especially since there is no error code.
[image]

Also, No "App" or "Error" in questions?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same BadGateway

The above proposed solution works but only if you are performing a Sharepoint action of 'Get file content'. There is no option in the trigger action which you used.("When a file is created in a folder").

It is pretty ugly so has anyone else managed to get rid of the BadGateway issue?

So in the "get file content" action there is the option to choose the site and that works.
The next item is the File identifier box. All I did was type in the text myfilepathandname and then I saved the logic app.

Then I went into codeview and replaced myfilepathandname with
/documents/folder a/folder b/folder c/filename.csv.

- You have to use %252f for any forwardslash(/) you have
- you have to replace spaces with %2b

it looks horrible but if you put that in the file identifier box, it works

[GetFileContent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdWsz.jpg)

I don't have enough points to paste the image in but you can look at it via the link.

My File Identifier looks like this when you put the slashes and spaces back
/Documents/1230000 Tech & Bus Services/1231814 Bus Systems/Integration/PowerBiTargets/2019_reforecast.csv

So try pasting in the same (with %252f and %2b) into your Folder Id box.

I will try it myself but if I were looking for files added to my PowerBiTargets folder I would use this in the Folder Id box. Just key it in or build it in notepad and then paste it.

%252fDocuments%252f1230000%2bTech%2b&%2bBus Services%252f1231814%2bBus Systems%252fIntegration%252fPowerBiTargets

**Update:**

I tried my suggestion in a trigger for "When a file is created or modified in a folder" and it works

Step 1
Create a "When a file is created or modified in a folder" Sharepoint trigger

1. Choose your site
2. Type (or paste) the full folder path you wish to watch for changes in

[When a file is created or modified in a folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnLoI.png)

Step 2
Do something with the files detected as added or modified (I write to Azure blob storage)

Comment: Thanks, I had I high hopes, but that returned a 404 'Not Found' error when I tried running it. I went ahead and just dropped a file in the parent directory, to avoid using any spaces or "/" and it returned the same error. Which is leading me to believe that there are some permissions errors or something of that sort causing the break.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this issue two days ago. Solved it by navigating to the folder in Sharepoint and creating a new Power Automate project. I then downloaded it, copyed the reference, deleted the Project, and pasted it back in Logic App.

Weirdly enough, even though it works, the Bad Gateway error still shows on the folder icon.

Comment: Interesting. This looks fruitful. I've gotten the flow to work, and I've ecported, however the format must not be right since the Logic App rejects it. I followed this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/export-from-microsoft-flow-logic-app-template. But I'm having an error "azureblob_1' could not be found." Which is odd since it's there in my resource group.

Comment: You really only need to replace the `triggers.When_a_file_is_created_in_a_folder` part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the exactly the same issue with my Logic Apps all of a sudden. Like yourself i have vast experience with Logic Apps so i know it's nothing i'm doing wrong.

A work around for this is the following:

1. Leave speech marks in the 'File identifier' field and save the Logic App
2. Go into code view and look for the 'Path' of the this connector
3. At the end of the line you should see:

   ```
   files/@{encodeURIComponent('%252fShared%2bDocuments%252fSupport%2bUpdate%2bScript%252fUserEnabled%2bList%2bNew.csv')}/content
   ```
4. Here shows the format of mine that i've pasted in that will **Get File Content**
5. It translates to /Shared Documents/Support Update Script/UserEnabled List New.csv

Comment: Joshua,  you should use **comments** (like I'm doing with your answer) down below the original question in order to ask for more information. **Answer** is reserved for providing a solution to the question being asked.

Comment: I've just registered and don't have a reputation of 50 to provide a comment to the question asked.

Comment: I understand the rep struggle. Let me give this a shot this afternoon. Thanks.

Comment: There wasn't a direct match in the code, but I attempted to implement the work around to no avail

Comment: Can you provide an example of yours?